# MySQL: COUNT statements: Why does it only display one order id?

Tags: mysql, syntax, count

I'm attempting to run a small sequence where the compiler will list the order ids that are greater than or equal to 600. At the same time, I am counting the numbers that each order_id has.

When I run my code, I only receive one order_id, whereas I have plenty that are greater than 600. '

Note: I do not receive any errors.

**Sequence:**

```
/*Exercise 1*/    
SELECT orders.order_id as 'Order ID', 
       COUNT(DISTINCT order_details.item_id) as 'Total Items'
FROM order_details
JOIN orders on order_details.order_id = orders.order_id
WHERE orders.order_id >= 600
ORDER BY orders.order_id ASC;
```

I did actually attempt to try it without DISTINCT and had the same result. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

*Removed other code as it was not needed.

Additional Question: Is it possible to use a count statement as a means to order? Like so:

```
SELECT orders.order_id as 'Order ID', 
       COUNT(order_details.item_id) as 'Total Items'
FROM order_details
JOIN orders on order_details.order_id = orders.order_id
WHERE orders.order_id >= 600
GROUP BY orders.order_id
ORDER COUNT(order_details.item_id) ASC;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COUNT` is an aggregating function it would aggregate all the rows into one row, unless you set a `GROUP BY` clause which it will group on
What you'll want is the following:

```
/*Exercise 1*/    
SELECT orders.order_id as 'Order ID', 
       COUNT(order_details.item_id) as 'Total Items'
FROM order_details
JOIN orders on order_details.order_id = orders.order_id
WHERE orders.order_id >= 600
GROUP BY orders.order_id
ORDER BY orders.order_id ASC;
```

The distinct would only be neccesary if there are duplicate entrees on the same item_id, i'm guessing there is not so i removed it.

Some useful links:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Edit, answer on second question:

Yes this is definitely possible and the example you've given is correct and should give the desired result

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the fast response, and I totally get you mean. I was actually just visiting the COUNT link at w3 schools and I tried the simulators to find that you were 100% correct on that. Thank you for the group by link as well. ALso, thank you for putting it in example with my sequence of code. It's all very much appreciated! :)

Comment: Probably professional jealousy, but SO doesn't seem to like w3 much.

Comment: No problem ^^ always good to be able to help :) if you have anymore questions about it i'd be happy to help. if you have no more questions on this don't forget to mark an answer, if you do then ask away ^^

Comment: @Strawberry haha, really?  i mean it's not always the best site, but it's a lot less complicated then some other sites out there and contains easy examples to understand. i guess they'd just want the mysql definition page? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: To be fair, SO seems to have started warming to them a bit in recent months. Perhaps they got better, or perhaps we got worse ;-)

Comment: Jester, I do have a quick question about the use of the COUNT statement as an ORDER BY. Is it possible?

Comment: sure, go ahead. That's why i asked if you did ^^

Comment: @SierraMcGivney yes, you can order on an the result of an aggregating function as in your example, can't you just try it out and see for yourself? :p

Comment: Thanks for your help again! :)

Comment: No problem, if you don't have access to a database to just try you can always go http://sqlfiddle.com/ and try it there, you can also find sites like this one for php and (html, javascript and css) Again happy to help, and good luck, although i feel like you'll manage :) ^^

Comment: Oh, well you see I did it at first, and it didn't run, but it turned out I had another error in the code. I figured out the error after I asked the question. I thought that maybe it wasn't allowed. But thank you again for all of your help.